# DOM table different column widths by row

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to allow a singular table to have dynamic column widths row-by-row?

Example of what I have and what I'm trying to achieve:

https://jsfiddle.net/s33c8n7m/1/

```css
td {
  border: solid !important;
  border-width: 1px 1px !important;
  border-color: #808080 !important;
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight: bold;">Test Short:</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">Test text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight: bold;">TEST VERY LOOO O OOOO OOOO OOOO OONG:</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">test text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<b>Desired:</b>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="table-layout:fixed; font-weight: bold;">Test Short:</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">Test text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="table-layout:fixed; font-weight: bold;">TEST VERY LOOO O OOOO OOOO OOOO OONG::</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">test text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Resize the width of the display to see how the column widths of each row can change independently.

But I need a way of doing this with a single table.

Comment: You can do this with `div`s based table (like in bootstrap grid for example) but not in the regular `table` system.

Comment: I need each column to be able to dynamically resize, I have no way of knowing what data will be displayed.

Comment: I just ended up using the second method i posted, its not ideal but it works.